# The vue <router-link> don't want to work as a link, it shows as a simple text. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using vue js in laravel project. I want to make my project single page application, so I need vue routes. I installed the latest versions of vue-loader, vue-template-compiler, vue, vue-router, but the problem still exists.

app.js

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

import {createApp} from "vue";
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Login from './components/auth/Login.vue'
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";

window.$ = require( "jquery" );

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'Register',
        component: Register
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.APP_URL),
    routes
})

const app = createApp({});
app.component('login', Login);
app.mount('#app');
export default router
```

vue.blade.php

```html
<body>
<div id="app">
    <router-link to="/register">Harrison</router-link>
    <router-view> </router-view>
</div>

<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get tired of searching in google for the answers, nothing helps. Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you adding `router-link` tag in blade file. it will not work in blade file. you have to create vue file for that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `app.js` is not registering the Vue Router plugin. To register the plugin, use [`app.use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use):

```js
// main.js
const router = createRouter(/*...*/)

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router) 
app.mount('#app')
```

Also there's no need to export the router from `app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Vue app component. Assume this is the content of a file called `app.vue`:

```
<template>
    <router-link to="/register">Harrison</router-link>
    <router-view> </router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
}
</script>
```

Then make your html file look like that:

```
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, change some lines in your `app.js`file:

```
...
import App from "app.vue"
...
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
...
```

And then it should work.
(Btw: are you on `Vue2` or on `Vue3`?)